# Initialising array of strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, structure

So, I'm basically trying to assign my structure with strings as 0, so then I could change some values later, but I'm getting the warning of "strcpy makes pointer from integer without a cast"
and the code is not working how can I fix it?

my structure is this

```
struct node{
char ID[3];
char Name[40];
char Code[3];
};
```

and here is my function

```
void initialiseArray(struct node* arr){
int i;
for(i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
    strcpy(arr[i].ID[3], "0");
    strcpy(arr[i].Name[40], "0");
    strcpy(arr[i].Code[3], "0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing an index on the `char` arrays when calling `strcpy`? Especially one that is out of bounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[i].ID[3]` in the function definition must be `arr[i].ID`. Same for the other two fields. `arr[i].ID[3]` is a [nonexistant] character of a string, not the string.